# Vim is polluting clipboard with netrw_dirhist stuff

Tags: os-clipboard

Every time I launch vim I have this in clipboard:

```
let g:netrw_dirhistmax  =10
let g:netrw_dirhist_cnt =8
let g:netrw_dirhist_1=...
let g:netrw_dirhist_2=...
let g:netrw_dirhist_3=...
let g:netrw_dirhist_4=...
let g:netrw_dirhist_5=...
let g:netrw_dirhist_6=...
let g:netrw_dirhist_7=...
let g:netrw_dirhist_8=...
```

I know, `vim -u NONE`, remove plugins one by one... Just thought maybe somebody knows what's causing it.

Comment: Someone somehow do something like this `let @+="blah-blah-blah"`?
`let @+=` sets vim register `"+` aka system clipboard. Look carefully your `.vimrc` and plugins scripts.

Comment: *"I know, vim -u NONE, remove plugins one by one... Just thought maybe somebody knows what's causing it."* -> So did this fix it?

Comment: Haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very bad answer (down-votes deserved)

1) **netrw** has to do with history of remote files editing.

(from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9850662/2991627:

**netrw** is a kind of vim plugin/script which supports reading and writing files across networks. .netrwhist is a history file which maintains all the directories that were modified. So whenever you modify the contents of ~/.vim it adds one entry in .netrwhist  )

---

2) Somewhere (.vimrc, .netrwhist or similar) you may have some operation that
changes register `"+` or `"*`  (look for `/[*+]` in those files...) and see if there is something strange...

Comment: Not a bad answer at all.

Comment: @Wildcard, thank you; (it is too speculative).

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the contents of .netrwhist, a file typically placed in ~/.vim/.netrwhist.  I suggest upgrading your netrw and see if that fixes the problem, because I'm not seeing it: http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW .